# Undefined method '+' error Rails, Net/http

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Actually the problem was not with the '+' sign. But i doubted it because, it was the only '+' sign in that page.

The line which causes the error is "- res = req.request_head(imageurl.path)"
My code:

```
- req = Net::HTTP.new(imageurl.host, imageurl.port)
- res = req.request_head(imageurl.path)
```

throws the error "ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass):"
what is the issue?

Thanks a lot for all the helps & sorry for the inconveniences caused.

But the issue is still not fixed.

Answer (score 4):

You can use standard ruby methods to achieve what you want in more elegant way, for example:

```
- products.shuffle.each_with_index do |product, i|
  - if i == 24                              
    %li.product                  
      .image{:style => "width:180px;"}
```

If you need that `li` after each 25th product, you can use `each_slice`:

```
- products.shuffle.each_slice(25) do |items|
  %li.product                  
    .image{:style => "width:180px;"}
```

Though it's not an answer to your question (other answers should work for you), but this approach is more rubiest.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the method `to_i` on the object called `scount` is returning nil. An investigation into what the class of `scount` may be seems like the next step to me.

Update with some code after comments below;

```
- scount = 1
- products.shuffle.each do |product|
  - if scount == 25                              
    %li.product                  
      .image{:style => "width:180px;"}
  - scount += 1
```

Comment: that is weird. is this the first place where you use the variable? try to initiate scount outside the loop instead - updating my answer with a snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work  -

```
- products.shuffle.each do |product|
  scount = defined?(scount) ? scount.to_i : 0
  scount += 1
  - if scount == 25                              
   %li.product                  
    .image{:style => "width:180px;"}
```